# Появление полосы прокрутки в сss и vue3

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, scrollbar

Нашел код по оформлению полосы прокрутки [Transparent scrollbar with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200639/transparent-scrollbar-with-css)
.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <style type="text/css">
          html, body {
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
          }

          body {
              overflow: overlay;
          }

          .div1 {
              background: grey;
              margin-top: 200px;
              margin-bottom: 20px;
              height: 20px;
          }

          ::-webkit-scrollbar {
              width: 7px;
              height: 10px;
          }

          ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
              background: rgb(144, 144, 144);
          }

          ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
              background: rgb(255,255,255);
          }

          </style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>YouTube</title>
  </head>
  <body class="text-gray-600 bg-gray-50" style="overflow: overlay">
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <TheHeader />
  <!--<TheSidebarSmall />-->
  <TheSidebar />
  <!--<TheSidebarMobile />-->
  <TheCategories />
  <!--<TheVideos />-->
</template>

<script>
import TheHeader from './components/TheHeader.vue'
import TheSidebarSmall from './components/TheSidebarSmall.vue'
import TheSidebar from './components/TheSidebar.vue'
import TheSidebarMobile from './components/TheSidebarMobile.vue'
import TheCategories from './components/TheCategories.vue'
import TheVideos from './components/TheVideos.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    TheHeader,
    TheSidebarSmall,
    TheSidebar,
    TheSidebarMobile,
    TheCategories,
    TheVideos
  }
}
</script>
```

TheCategories.vue

```
<template>
    <section class="pt-16 md:pl-24 xl:pl-64 w-full fixed bg-white bg-opacity-95 z-10">
    <div class="border-t border-b max-w-screen-2xl m-auto">
      <div class="py-3 flex space-x-4 overflow: overlay text-sm whitespace-no-wrap">
        <a href="#" class="px-5 mx-2 py-1 transition bg-gray-600 border border-gray-700 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-500 text-white">All</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Trucks</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Tools</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Machines</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Engines</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Snow</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Ships</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Roads</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Tanks</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Building</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Mars</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Woodworking</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Tractors</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Songs</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">TV Shows</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Football</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Planes</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Live</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Streets</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Math</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Programming</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

Только непонятно как сделать, чтобы полоса прокрутки появлялась только при наведении мыши на компонент или перемещалась при перемещении мыши по компоненту, чтобы бы было как на https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-FhWbGlJPfa2QOklK-4ED0gZFg6gbmyE в правом боковом сайдбаре.
Как это сделать

1. на javascript;
2. на vue?

На vue пытался сделать

```
<template>
    <section class="pt-16 md:pl-24 xl:pl-64 w-full fixed bg-white bg-opacity-95 z-10 overflow-auto">
    <div class="border-t border-b max-w-screen-2xl m-auto">
      <div class="py-3 flex space-x-4 overflow: overlay text-sm whitespace-no-wrap">
        <a href="#" class="px-5 mx-2 py-1 transition bg-gray-600 border border-gray-700 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-500 text-white">All</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Trucks</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Tools</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Machines</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Engines</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Snow</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Ships</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Roads</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Tanks</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Building</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Mars</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Woodworking</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Tractors</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Songs</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">TV Shows</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Football</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Planes</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Live</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Streets</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Math</a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2 px-3 py-1 transition bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Programming</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<style scoped>
section::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 7px;
  height: 10px;
  background: transparent;
}

section::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: transparent;
}

section::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: rgb(255,255,255);
}

section:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgb(144, 144, 144);
}

</style>
```

но в результате получил, что скроллбар внизу для категорий (All, Trucks, Tools и т.д.) не появляется **при наведении на него мышью**, т.е. hover не срабатывает (скроллбар отображается изначально, при наведении мыши он не появляется, при покидании компонента мышью он не исчезает, не срабатывает

```
section::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 7px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

section::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: transparent;
  /* background: rgb(144, 144, 144);*/
}

section::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
/* background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); */
  background: rgb(255,255,255);
}

section:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgb(144, 144, 144);
}
```

,

только цвет полоски (светло-серый и цвет фона - белый)

```
background-color: rgb(144, 144, 144);
background: rgb(255,255,255);
```

устанавливаются и то не при hover-е.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как добиться, чтобы скроллбар работал для vue компонента.

Comment: Почему минусуете? Я новичок, у меня не получается. Я привел весь нужный код, который у меня не работает (в частности для компонента Vue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте псевдокласс `hover` для изменения цвета скроллбара при наведении на элемент:

```css
.body {
  background: #212121;
}

.slides {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.slide {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.slides::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 4px;
  background: transparent;
}

.slides::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.slides:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #717171;
}
```

```html
<body class="body">

<div class="slides">
  <div class="slide">Слайд 1</div>
  <div class="slide">Слайд 2</div>
  <div class="slide">Слайд 3</div>
  <div class="slide">Слайд 4</div>
  <div class="slide">Слайд 5</div>
  <div class="slide">Слайд 6</div>
  <div class="slide">Слайд 7</div>
  <div class="slide">Слайд 8</div>
  <div class="slide">Слайд 9</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: а как сделать ,чтобы полоса прокрутки появлялась при наведении на **Vue** компонент, к примеру на компонент **TheCategories**?

Comment: помогите справиться со vue.